# How to get the userID to complete the change of password?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am try to create a change password page, but i do not know how to get the user id(email) out to complete the change.

here is my change password page,

```html
<form name="Change Password" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="adminHandleChangePassword.php">

  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="InputPassword2">New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" name="newPassword">
    <label for="InputPassword3">Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Change Password" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>
```

And this is my adminHandleChangePassword.php page,

```html
<?php

session_start();

require 'dbfunction.php';

$con = getDbConnect();

$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['newPassword']);
$password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['confirmPassword']);
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['email']);

if ($password1 != $password2) { echo "Your passwords do not match.";}

else if (mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE adminaccount (email,password) VALUES ('$user', AES_ENCRYPT('$password1','tw8520'))"))
    {echo "You have successfully changed your password.";}

else { mysqli_error($con); }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

the database data,

Comment: You can add a `WHERE` clause to your `UPDATE`. Do `UPDATE adminaccount SET email = 'y', password = 'z' WHERE email = 'x'`. At the moment your query will reset the email and password columns of all rows in this table, presumably not what you want.

Comment: i changed the statement to else if (mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE adminaccount SET password = 'AES_ENCRYPT('$password1','st2220')' WHERE email = $user")) but it did not update the database

Comment: Your AES function should not be in quotes - quotes are only for strings.

Answer (score 2):

do this first. the form of the username must have a value in order for the user to see his old username. hope this helps. feel free to ask questions:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adminaccount WHERE email={$_SESSION['email']}");
if($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
 echo " <input type='email' class='form-control' value='".$fetch['email']."' name='email'> ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user email in your database you don't need the userID. The email I suppose is unique or maybe you have the user_id stored in $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some parts of code and it worked,

```html
if ($password1 != $password2) { echo "Your passwords do not match.";}

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE adminaccount SET password = AES_ENCRYPT('$password1','st2220') WHERE email = '$user'");

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
     echo "You have successfully changed your password.";
    } else {
          echo "NO record updated.";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```